# RAML 1.0 - Multiple Examples for a Single Response

Tags: syntax, raml

I am unable to find any code anywhere that demonstrates using a `!include` for multiple examples. I'm trying to attempt the following:

```
200:
  description: Successful project creation
  body:
    application/json:
      type: JiraResponseSuccess
      example: !include examples/jira/projects/success/CreateSuccess.json
400:
  description: User error
  body:
    application/json:
      type: JiraResponseError
      examples:
        username: 
          !include examples/jira/projects/fail/user/UsernameFail.json
        projectKey: 
          !include examples/jira/projects/fail/user/ProjectKeyFail.json
```

The first example renders fine (where there's only a single response) whereas the second does not. The [syntax](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#defining-examples-in-raml) is correct, but I don't understand why it's choking on the `!include` statements. Do I have an error or do I just need to wait for the tooling to catch up?

Comment: Look like multiple responses are simply not implemented yet: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/issues/24

Comment: It's added in recent raml and works for me the above way.

Answer (score 5):

We have been doing the same thing for our RAML documentation, plus this solution also works for RAML version 0.8.  You have a lot of flexibility with how you change the content type, and you can even include spaces and other basic symbols for readability.

As @manatico stated, the content types *do not* have to be a valid type, as RAML doesn't validate it.  It just recognizes that there is a difference, which allows multiple examples to be listed.  For providing clarity to customers, I would recommend prefacing the actual content type, but follow it with whatever suits your needs for providing additional examples.

```
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json - Example - Filtering by AppId:
             example: |
                { 
                   "tagId": "475889c9-773d-462a-a4ec-099242308170"
                   "appId": "12"
                   "tagName": "school",
                   "status": "ACTIVE"
                }
          application/json - Example - No Filtering:
             example: |
                {
                   "tagId": "58237aa0-3fa6-11e6-a16b-6d3f576c1098",
                   "tagName": "exercise",
                   "status": "ACTIVE"
                },
                {
                   "tagId": "06b8b7b5-8e6b-40e9-9e48-f87dec0665e4",
                   "tagName": "camping",
                   "status": "INACTIVE"
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify different content types for the body response examples, even if they aren't actually real content types:

```
200:
  body:
    role/admin:
      example: !include http/list-res-200.json
    role/admin-Search-for-User:
      example: !include http/search-as-admin-res-200.json
    role/member-Search-for-User:
      example: !include http/search-as-member-res-200.json
```

Just for documentation works fine, I parsed to HTML with [RAML2HTML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raml2html) and all went without problem.